# Connecting to ssh using proxy

Tags: proxy

I'm using putty and I want to be able to connect to a ssh server with a different ip every time. How do I do this?

I'm not sure if I use tunnel or what steps to take. If you have a tutorial that would be great.

Comment: You want to use a different proxy each time?

Comment: Ya, just random proxies from anywhere. As long as they are somewhat fast.

Answer (score 0):

See this: https://vscentrum.be/neutral/documentation/client/windows/PuTTY-proxy

That link describes how to use a command to configure a LOCAL proxy, mainly:

```
plink -agent -l %user %proxyhost -nc %host:%port
```

Now you can probably write a batch file that chooses randomly from a list of proxies and substitutes %user and %proxyhost in this plink command. (Or better yet, moves a proxy from a list of available proxies into a list of used proxies.)

Comment: Is there another way this can be done, I don't have a vsc login and I can't find a place to make one.

Comment: I can't help you with finding proxy servers to connect to, that's up to you. There are lists out there. Once you have a list of proxies you can use it together with this method to achieve what you requested.

Comment: I have a list, but I don't have a log in or username or anything like that. I just have a bunch of ips in a txt file. Where in the link you shared would I start?

Comment: The important part is using a local command to start a proxy connection before your ssh connection. Try to get your proxy running using plink, you might not need the options specified in this case. Once you can connect to a proxy with plink, make a batch file that chooses with prosyhost to connect to and run the plink command and put that batch file in the local command box for putty.

Comment: How do I make it connect with plink. This is what I've done so far:

Changed the options to local
Put this in the Telnet command or local proxy command: plink -agent -l %user %proxyhost -nc %host:%port

http://prntscr.com/37fghf

Where do I go from here.